# How to select count(*) in criteria api?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have a query generated by hibernate criteria api which takes a pretty much time to execute:

```
select count (entity.id) 
from table 
where field1 in ('...') and field2 in ('...') and ...
```

I've replaced entity.id with '*':

```
select count (*) 
from table 
where field1 in ('...') and field2 in ('...') and ...
```

And for now it works pretty well for some reasons, but I can't generate this query by criteria api. I'am creating Root like this:

```
Root<MyEntity> root cq.from(MyEntity.class);
```

Is there any ways to generate sql query with select count(*) not with count(id)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA 2.0: count for arbitrary CriteriaQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997587/jpa-2-0-count-for-arbitrary-criteriaquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(1)` which is equivalent by doing `criteriaBuilder.count(criteriaBuilder.literal(1))`

Comment: hi, I had this problem for a while, criteriaBuilder.literal(1) not working in older hibernate, sum(1) works like count(*), I test criteriaBuilder.sum(criteriaBuilder.literal(1)) and my problem solved